# Calculating the delay between write and read on I2C in Linux

Tags: c, linux, archlinux, i2c, archlinux-arm

I am currently working with I2C in Arch Linux Arm and not quite sure how to calculate the absolute minimum delay there is required between a write and a read. If i don't have this delay the read naturally does not come through. I have just applied `usleep(1000)` between the two commands, which works, but its just done empirically and has to be optimized to the real value (somehow). But how?.

Here is my code sample for the `write_and_read` function i am using:

```
int write_and_read(int handler, char *buffer, const int bytesToWrite, const int bytesToRead) {
    write(handler, buffer, bytesToWrite);
    usleep(1000);
    int r = read(handler, buffer, bytesToRead);
    if(r != bytesToRead) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally there's no need to wait. If your writing and reading function is threaded somehow in the background (why would you do that???) then synchronizating them is mandatory.

I2C is a very simple linear communication and all the devices used my me was able to produce the output data within microsecs.

Are you using 100kHz, 400kHz or 1MHz I2C?

Edited:
After some discuss I suggest you this to try:

```
void dataRequest() {
    Wire.write(0x76);
    x = 0;
}

void dataReceive(int numBytes)
{
    x = numBytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++) {
        Wire.read();
    }
}
```

Where x is a global variable defined in the header then assigned 0 in the setup(). You may try to add a simple if condition into the main loop, e.g. if x > 0, then send something in serial.print() as a debug message, then reset x to 0.

With this you are not blocking the I2C operation with the serial traffic.

Comment: Thats what i thought initially, but it does not work without the delay between the write and read.

Comment: What is the write function? What device are you communicating with?

Comment: I am using the `linux/i2c-dev.h`. The devices are simple Atmel/Arduino controllers.

Comment: On Arduino is there any delay in your main loop or in the receive / request events?

Comment: I have no delays in my loop what so ever. Actually my loop is empty as we speak. There are only the interrupts for the receive and request functions.

Comment: Other options in my mind to try: clear all in receive and request events to not block the code there, then if it works, try to do everything in the receive event, request event should be a simple answering function without any "logic" there.

Comment: I only return data in the request, and do pretty much everything in the receive as you describe. I have a logic analyzer which i intend to use in order to determine the frequency the I2C bus is running with.

Comment: Is some part of your arduino code public? I would try to run in my architecture.

Comment: This is basically what i have now: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b62be94302c26b4c6fb

Comment: Serial communication can slows the processing and in this case your code is delaying the I2C communication. I edited my answer with some code, could you please try it?

Comment: I just did the test and only the først receive command goes through, everything else afterwards does not trigger the recieve callback.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to read the data you sent. Modified the code with a for loop.

Comment: Very stupid mistake. I forgot to read in the Arduino. FYI i did not downvote.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you in the end.